# Alternative to link_directories when find_package cannot be used

Tags: cmake

I'm developing a scientific code that needs to link against nonstandard packages and thus something like `find_package` doesn't work for me. The user must be able to specify exactly which directories and which libraries are linked against (two cache variables for this: LIBRARY_PATHS and LIBRARIES). Because I'm creating the targets early in the topmost CMakeLists.txt and then using all kinds of `target_*` commands to build them up, I cannot use `link_directories`, which doesn't work if the targets have already been defined.

Is there an easy way to specify the directories to be included in linking after the target has been defined? I'm considering defining a macro which takes LIBRARY_PATHS and LIBRARIES and using `find_library` converts LIBRARIES into a list of libraries with full paths. However, such a hack seems to go against the CMake philosophy, so I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Added a link to some of the target functions you mentioned in your OP, might help out when looking at this question:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_directories.html

Comment: What do you mean by "such a hack seems to go against the CMake philosophy"?

Comment: @thomas_f The way I understand it, in CMake you're supposed to use helper functions such as `find_package` that do stuff automatically in the background and not modify things like linker flags directly yourself. Doing string manipulation and pasting the result into linker flags is usually advised against.

Comment: @RaulLaasner Sure that is generally correct, but there is nothing wrong with using `find_library()` to obtain a full path to the library. This is how its done in `Find`/`Config`-modules (these are the modules that are read by `find_package()`. It sounds like you might be interested in the latter part of my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to specify the directories to be included in linking after the target has been defined?

You can add linker flags to a specific target by using: `set_target_properties(<target> PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS <flags>)`. In your case, `<flags>` would be a path list where each path is prefixed by the appropriate linker flag, (`-L` if you're using Clang/GCC).

**Example:** `-L<path1> -L<path2>`

> I'm considering defining a macro which takes LIBRARY_PATHS and LIBRARIES and using find_library converts LIBRARIES into a list of libraries with full paths. However, such a hack seems to go against the CMake philosophy, so I'm wondering if there is a better way.

You could consider creating a `CMake` target out of the result of `find_library()`. This approach is very common in `Find` and `Config`-modules. This might get you started:

```
foreach(_LIBRARY ${LIBRARIES})
    find_library(_LIB ${_LIBRARY} PATHS ${LIBRARY_PATHS})
    if(_LIB)
        message(STATUS "Found '${_LIBRARY}' at '${_LIB}'")
        add_library(${_LIBRARY} UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
        set_target_properties(${_LIBRARY} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${_LIB})
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find '${_LIBRARY}'.")
    endif()
    unset(_LIB CACHE)
endforeach()
```

This will create and map a `CMake` target (imported library) to each of the entries in `LIBRARIES`. You would then link to any of these targets just as usual: `target_link_libraries(<target> <SCOPE> <some-item-from-LIBRARIES>)`.

**Why `add_library()`, why not just use the result from `find_library()`?**

You can. The future call to `target_link_libraries()` would look exactly the same. However, creating a "true" `CMake` target adds more flexibility, as you can get/set properties on a `CMake` target. [See here for some examples](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets#Importing_Targets).

Comment: I like the first part. With a few extra lines this can be turned into `target_link_directories` (which doesn't currently exist). Regarding the second part, why is the `add_library` part necessary? Why not keep it minimal and just have the macro return full paths to the libraries?

Comment: Also, thanks for providing a good example of when to use the `UNKNOWN` keyword.

Comment: @RaulLaasner I've updated my answer to add a possible justification for using `add_library()` instead of just exporting the result from `find_library()`.